# PHP, CSS class issue

Tags: php, css

I've been dealing with this problem like 3 days.

I have a PHP code that echo es images from database. The class IMG  is not responding, it should show  margin-bottom: 60px but it is not. I've putted the class in img class-name src but still nothing.

Thank you

```
<table class="table-image">    
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo ' 
<tr>  
<td> 
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['name'] ).'" height="480" width="550" class="img" " /> 
</td>
</tr>  
';  
}  
?>  
</table>
```

And CSS

```
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Why you store images in db? that's so bad and wrong!

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9xfofaoq/

Comment: You should probably combine all the answers below, as there are many different issues.

Comment: You should also look at the rendered HTML and see if anything's wonky there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="table-image">    
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>  
   <tr>  
     <td> 
       <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['name'] ); ?>" height="480" width="550" class="img" /> 
     </td>
    </tr>  
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: Escaping the `'` marks doesn't make sense. OP has already dropped out of the string with a `'`. Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Escaping the single quotes here is simply wrong. It'll cause `syntax error, unexpected ''name\'] ).'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Answer (score 2):

You have two quotes at the end.

```
 class="img" " />
```

Comment: It seems to work fine with that, though: https://jsfiddle.net/9xfofaoq/ (in Chrome, at least)

Comment: Since it's bad HTML, it may be browser-dependent.

Comment: nahh, its not that. I've edited it but still nothing.

Comment: @urosv  can you please check once my answer?